# Why isn't my angular redirect working within the firebase onAuthStateChanged function?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm in the process of improving my firebase/angular authentication.

What I want to do is redirect the user to the relevant page based on the claim set on the user.

The code below is working but the redirect doesn't work and the user isn't redirected to their account.

Why isn't this redirecting?

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {}


authStatusListener(){
    console.log('authStatusListener');
    return this.firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
      if(user){
        this.router.navigate(['/user/my-account']);
        user.getIdTokenResult().then(idTokenResult => {

        })
      }
    });
  }
```

The function above is invoked from `app.component.ts`:

```
ngOnInit(){
  console.log('ngOnInit');
  this.authService.authStatusListener();
}
```

Comment: I can imagine some reasons: the firebaseAuth runs outside the ngZone and never has an onAuthStateChanged detected. OnAuthStateChanged never happens for any other reason, and the third that the user is not existing. So basically all lines from the return on could fail. Debug step by step. You can use "tap(console.log)". Furthermore: the user.getIdTokenResult()  might potentially not happen as you navigate away - depends on where your router-outlet is located (so the paths also have to be set correctly). - Oh and don't forget to subscribe to the observable :)!

Comment: @Nadine Thanks for your reply.  I can console.log the user successfully, I can also see the claim on the user.  So it seems that the firebaseAuth is working and onAuthStateChanged is also working.  The authStatusListener is defined in the AuthService service class.  Not sure if that makes any difference.  Is there any other info I can give that would help resolve this?

Comment: I recently saw that happening when a service wasn't inside the NgZone(the firebase service might be suspicious), one could log but the change detection didn't take place. So you can try to log NgZone.isInAngularZone() before the navigation. If not, the service needs to be registered at the right time and the right place, or you can manually trigger change detection as a hack to proof the problem. I still find it strange that there is no subscribe () on the firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged visible. Does it return an Observable?

Comment: And is the path you're trying to navigate to registered among the routes for the router-outlet (routing can be logged as an option in the module where the routerModule is imported)? Furthermore, could be a guarded path to which navigation is not possible and thus gets a redirect. This all should be visible when logging the navigation.

Comment: It seems that I am returning the observer and not the auth state from inside the observer's callback.